# Certain JPEG images not visible in Adobe Form while others are

Tags: pdf-generation, adobe, printform, adobe-form

I have this strange problem where certain JPEG images are not visible in Adobe Form while others are. What could be causing this?

Thank you in advance,

Joshua

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the colorspace of the JPEG image. Convert the JPEG to the YCbCr colorspace to fix it. You can do so with ImageMagick for example. This Linux command would do the trick:

```
mogrify -colorspace YCbCr <your_image.jpeg>
```